# Qlik Sense: Adding function to my Apps so renew data on excel can be imported?

Tags: excel, business-intelligence, qliksense

I would like to ask for some advise as below:

My Qlik license (QAP) is not allow to use HUB to edit APPs, it is for display APPs to our portal which is working fine. We had separated Qlik HUB server to created APPs.

The problem is we want our display APPs on portal also can have feature to import a new excel data file (it is same excel file data that the apps was built on but the content may update), do we have any Extensions or Widgets project allow to do this?

Comment: Please talk to Qlik support for this case.

Comment: tobi6 -thanks for your suggestion :).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure from your question what you are trying to achieve, do you want users to be able to manually refresh an app after making changes to a central held excel sheet?

If so, try this extension [Qlik Sense Reload Button](http://branch.qlik.com/#!/project/56728f52d1e497241ae69836)